# What would cause html code formatting to disappear in php page?

Tags: php, html, formatting, whitespace

I have a page written with php where, for some reason, all of the plain html content of the file index.php goes on one line (look at the source)  The white space is preserved, but all the new-lines disappear.

I cannot come up with any reason why this would happen, short of a syntax error, but I went through with a fine toothed comb, and found nothing out of place.  This only happens on the index.php page.

Anyone have any Ideas what I should be looking for?  I can post more code if necessary.

```
<?php
//...
include('ssi/header.php');
?>

<div>
  <section id="charters">
    <h2><a href="charters.php">Tanker Chartering</a></h2>
     <!-- ... -->
```

The above code evaluates to something like this:

```
<div>      <section id="charters">        <h2><a href="charters.php">Tanker ...
```

Comment: The html source code format looks ok to me, I do see the code spread across multiple lines.

Comment: Well thats odd... why would that be different between me and you?  Is it a browser thing?

Comment: I should note, its only the code in my index.php file (between) `<div id="main" role="main">` and `<footer>` in the source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have linux server and you're using windows system. Different operating systems use different new line characters. Also, for one server my FTP client uploaded it with wrong formatting, and missed every line break.

Also applications like 
[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) gives you the ability to change formatting and linebreaks.

Comment: I do, and I am.  Not sure what to do about it though.  This only occurs for the one page, no matter how many times I re-upload... (also happens on XAMPP localhost)

Comment: [try this](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/document-properties/newline-format) if you use windows and check if formatting is different on your index page than on other pages.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the encoding of the file combined with the transfer mode on the ftp from which you downloaded/uploaded the file.  Try using something like notepad2, and saving the file in UTF-8 rather than ANSI.  Also upload/download with your FTP program in binary not ASCII.  That stopped all of my newline issues with PHP.

Comment: Well that looked so promising...  but alas, I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that your hosting provider is doing some kind of minimization for you? no newlines means less characters pused down the wire.

Comment: for only the index.php?  It is happening on my localhost as well.  Also the site is on dev.soundtanker.com (different host) and doing the same thing